# RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView image field when i update a field in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

i created this api which has a model collection where there is an image field.
the list and collection creation part is not a problem but the part of detail especially update has a problem, when I want to update a field I get an error because the image field is not filled in.

How can I fix this, I would like if I don't change the image the file will remain the same.

model

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    description = models.TextField()
    discount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='collection/')
    active = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializer

```
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'discount', 'image', 'active')
```

views

```
class CollectionDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    queryset = Collection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CollectionSerializer
```

url

```
path('collections/', CollectionListCreate.as_view(), name="collections-list"),
path('collections/<int:pk>/', CollectionDetail.as_view(), name="collection-detail"),
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your model, `Discount` and `Active` fields have default values. Everything else is a required field while creating and updating the object.

So if the image field is not compulsory, you can add `blank=True` to image field, so that it will not be required when submitting a form.

`image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='collection/', blank=True)`

OR

you can add required=False to serializer,

```
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'discount', 'image', 'active')
```